# How do you say "to hell with everything" in French?

Tags: expressions, usage

Would "au diable tout" work? Or would it be something else?

Comment: “Tout au diable” sounds more idiomatic to my non-native ears, the question of whether this is correct usage aside.

Comment: As often, this question is missing some context. Depending on the language register and what "everything" is referring to, several translations are possible.

Comment: Ce serait bien aussi de savoir ce que ça veut dire.

Comment: Just say "bof" and shrug.

Comment: Depends how harsh/obscene you want to be. Do you just want to convey annoyance/resignation, or do you really want to curse everyone?

Answer (score 23):

I'd say something along the lines of

> "Oh et puis merde !"

That's the first thing that would occur to me. To me, it's the most idiomatic way of saying "To hell with everything".

Truth is, I never ever hear people say "Au diable blablabla"...

In case you want to add more drama to your speech and be more vulgar, you might even say :

> Qu'il(s) aille(nt) se faire foutre avec...

I strongly urge you not to use the latter, but those are the most idiomatic translations.

Comment: I only ever heard "Au diable..." in "Au diable l'avarice". A more moderate version of your last sentence could be "Qu'ils aillent se faire voir", "Qu'ils aillent se faire voir chez les Grecs", "Qu'ils aillent se faire cuire un oeuf".

Comment: And the french-canadian equivalent: "Oh, pis de la marde!"

Comment: Thanks for your input Eric, « Qu’ils aillent se faire voir » and your other suggestions are quite good too indeed. Thanks Mart10 as well for this Canadian equivalent.

Comment: Only in French could you find subjunctives in a profanity. I love everything French, including that, lived there for several years, also Belgium, Switzerland and Germany. btw I am a Brit>>American

Answer (score 15):

The phrase *au diable* is idiomatic if it is followed by a mention of who/what you wish send to hell:

> Au diable Trump !
>
> Au diable les examens !
>
> Au diable les journalistes !
>
> Au diable le Brexit !
>
> Au diable tout le gouvernement !

It is not idiomatic, however, to use it with *tout* alone (*tout* being a pronoun then). You can use rather use the longer form *qu'il/elle/ils/elles aillent au diable* with *tous* if you refer to multiple persons or items:

> Qu'ils aillent tous au diable !

If by "to hell with everything", you want to express the idea that you are unhappy with everything and wish to "call it quits", you can use other phrases:

> Je laisse tout tomber.
>
> J'envoie tout valser.
>
> Je m'en fous de tout.

Answer (score 12):

We would not use *tout* on its own here,  to my mind the closest if you do not want to specify anything would be :

> Au diable tout cela !

Comment: Sounds perfectly correct and already seen in books, but very _vieillot_, I never hear it in modern spoken language, excepted maybe in a tv film or theater play, spoken from a aristocrat / old fasioned character,

Comment: My comment is about "_Au diable tout cela_", I agree with you that "_Au diable tout_" is indeed never heard of / wrong.

Answer (score 6):

"Au diable tout" is not a possibility in French; "tout au diable" is better from  no more than a syntaxic point au view (as user **Marroon** says in a comment) but wouldn't be found anywhere else than a special context: it can never appear in a translation of "to hell with everything" in today's spoken French, the reference to hell is not used in this context except in the literature or in the language of certain people (I heard it last from a doctor's mouth 15 years ago (Au diable l'avarice !)). Moreover, the most general possibility of a context in which all is considered to be rejected does not seem to exist in French.

**I**

> ([TLFi, diable¹](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/diable))  [En parlant de qqc. ou de qqn qu'on souhaiterait voir disparaître] Envoyer au diable, ou, sous la forme exclam. va, allez au diable!, **par ellipse : au diable!** Va au diable avec tes histoires! **Au diable tout cela!** Le cœur se rouille. Dérouillons-le. Et pour cela envoyons au diable les rancunes (BERNANOS, Lettres inéd., 1906, p. 1737). Oh! qu'il aille au diable avec son mulet! C'en est trop (CLAUDEL, Raviss. Scapin, 1952, préf., p. 1331). (user **LPH**'s bold type)

Then, the literal translation exists in the old language and in the literature. However, it applies more specifically to a given set of aspects or things determined by the context ; a translation for the most general context  will be considered after (**II**).

- Au diable tout cela !

In today's French, as said above, this form will be rather rare. In formal language you can say something like this ;

- Assez de tout ça !
- J'en ai assez de tout ça !
- J'en ai par dessus la tête de tout ça ! On en a par dessus la tête de tout ça !
- Fini, tout ça !
- Fini, toutes ces complications !

In the colloquial language those forms are common ;

- Il y en marre de tout ça ! (Y'en a marre de tout ça !) _ J'en ai marre de tout ça !

Unfortunately, all those translations correspond rather to "I'm fed up with all that"; the specific refreence to the wish of an elimination of what people are fed up with is not specifically a possibility, unless you use the language that is beginning to be obsolete (Au diable …).

**II**

The following form is termed "populaire, familier" in the TLFi (popular language, colloquial); it can be used in "**I**" for a limited context but is used in extreme cases by people that wish to reject a whole existence (family ties, work, social ethos) as they have in mind to start a new life.

- He said "To hell with everything!".
  *Il a dit « Je plaque tout ! »*

Comment: @personne Le caractère « tiret bas » est utilisé dans ce cas pour séparer deux choses sans rapport l'une avec l'autre sauf qu'elles sont d'une même catégorie (pour éviter de se servir d'une ligne supplémentaire) ; vaudrait-il mieux utiliser une puce comme séparateur ? Le sectionnement au moyen de chiffres et lettres me parait normal cependant, surtout lorsqu'il est annoncé par une introduction qui définit des parties; ces introductions sont rares dans le TLFi, néanmoins les entrées sont structurées de cette façon.

Comment: @personne Je parle du TLFi en tant qu'exemple général.  Il ne faut pas associer les symboles de division avec quelque partitionnement que ce soit : ils sont utilisés pour des quantité de choses, en particulier les chiffres romain, du sectionnement de preuves mathématiques au sectionnement de livres en chapitres en passant par des sectionnements d'entrées de dictionnaire.  « C'est plutôt dans la partie I que tu viens dire que II traitera plus généralement de X, c'est incohérent à mon avis.» : c'est exact, pas très bien faite cette réponse de ce point de vue-là. (1/2)

Comment: @personne  Comme dans des entrées de dictionnaire, il n'existe parfois pas une véritable relation entre deux parties ou bien on n'en voit aucune qui vaille la peine d'être mentionnée : on passe par exemple de la discussion d'un usage à un autre comme dans une entrée. (2/2)

Answer (score 4):

In Québécois, it is common, yet slightly vulgar, to say "D'la marde!" (literally "shit").

Comment: Ch'pu capab'! :)

Comment: Souvent précédé de « ah pis...» je crois.

Comment: ... and if we are in regional "ornate" phrases, a Belgian speaker would shout out a loud "fourte !"

Answer (score 0):

One commonly used expression for "to hell with everything" that doesn't have any religious connotation, isn't vulgar, sounds less extreme (since French speakers tend to use a more moderate language than Americans on average):

> Tant pis!

One would typically accompany this expression with a Gallic shrug.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the most polite forms might be “envoyer [somebody/something] au diable” or “tout envoyer au diable”, for example “j'envoie tout au diable” —— with the meaning “je laisse tout tomber”.

As far as I know, “envoyer au diable” is a bit archaic, “laisser tomber” is more modern, and both are colloquial :^)